# How do include a file path in a jQuery statement?

Tags: channel-entries, jquery, links

I am working on a photo portfolio [page](http://rouviere.com/photo/portfolio) that uses fancy-box to display larger images of the photographs. This also includes a optional Buy Now link in the title area of the photo.

The code for the photo thumbnails and related popup images is as follows:

```
{exp:low_reorder:entries set="portfolio_low_sort"  limit="500" }
    <a class="fancybox project {categories}{category_name} {/categories}"  href="{large_image}" title="{title}"><img src="{portfolio_thumbnail}" alt="{title}" width="262" height="175"></a>
{/exp:low_reorder:entries}
```

The jQuery code to include the Buy Now button and Pinterest link:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
openEffect  : 'elastic',
closeEffect : 'elastic',
nextEffect  : 'fade',
prevEffect  : 'fade',
nextSpeed   : 1250,
prevSpeed   : 1250,
beforeShow  : function () {
if (this.title) {

// Add pin it button
this.title += '&nbsp; <a href="//www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark"  data-pin-height="28"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_gray_28.png" /></a> ';

// Add buy now button
this.title += '<a href="/photo/image/{url_title}/" data-url="' + this.href + '"><span>Buy now</span></a> ';
}
},
helpers : {
title : {
type: 'inside'
}
}  
});
});
```

Currently I have a link to the image page where the user can Buy Now and this is where I get stuck. Because this is jQuery and not part of the entry, I am not sure how to bring in the "url_title" part.

Any guidance on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url title is not specified in your script. I would recommend putting the url title in a data attribute in the html code.

```
<a data-urltitle="{url_title}" class="fancybox project {categories}{category_name} {/categories}"  href="{large_image}" title="{title}">...</a>
```

then get that attribute in the js

```
// Add buy now button
var urltitle = this.data('urltitle');
this.title += '<a href="/photo/image/"+urltitle+"/" data-url="' + 
this.href + '"><span>Buy now</span></a> ';
}
```

Comment: Hi Johnathan, this is very close. I added the code as you noted above, but I get an error: this.data is not a function. Is there another way that should be written?

Comment: Sorry, I was using jquery's data method, so you might need to surround this with jquery selectors like $(this).data(...). If that works, I'll edit the answer to reflect that

Comment: You could also try var urltitle = $(this).attr('data-urltitle'); if you're stuck.